# How to avoid list has no attribute 'startswith' while initialising Elasticsearch connection in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch

`self.es = Elasticsearch([{'host': kwargs['ES_URL'], 'port': 9200}])`
This code above, generates an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1633, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 95, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 100, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pallet-0.0.0-py3.5.egg/pallet/tasks/datatable.py", line 241, in driver_de_datatable
    run_id=kwargs['run_id']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pallet-0.0.0-py3.5.egg/pallet/tasks/datatable.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.es = Elasticsearch([{'host': kwargs['ES_URL'], 'port': 9200}])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    self.transport = transport_class(_normalize_hosts(hosts), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 108, in __init__
    self.set_connections(hosts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 157, in set_connections
    connections = list(zip(connections, hosts))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 154, in _create_connection
    return self.connection_class(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.pool = pool_class(host, port=port, timeout=self.timeout, maxsize=maxsize, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 166, in __init__
    ConnectionPool.__init__(self, host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.host = _ipv6_host(host).lower()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 897, in _ipv6_host
    if host.startswith('[') and host.endswith(']'):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

The point to be noted is that it has been successful for so long but started generating an error for the first time.

Comment: Can you also share the rest of the code so that we understand better? 
The command you have posted has no code stating 'startswith' so I guess it's being used elsewhere in the code?

Comment: If you take a look at traceback, you will find that its the core library having this code.

The only change that I can do is to have improvements over my call. Isn't it?

Comment: Hm.. but you do understand what the code is trying to search. The query is possibly returning a list object instead of str object as the case used to be previously.
You might need to look at the raw data and check if it has got some incorrect attribute that is returning a list. 
Also, if you could post what the previously successful query was printing for the same raw data, it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the change in the declaration of ES' connection instance.

I use `self.es = Elasticsearch(kwargs['ES_URL'])` instead of `self.es = Elasticsearch([{'host': kwargs['ES_URL'], 'port': 9200}])`

This has also given me the capability of including multiple es clusters. Note: in ES_URL, I have to use the full IP along with the port number: [es_url]:9200